# Histogram in R: Converting into numeric

Tags: r

Suppose you have character values as the x values. Suppose you want to draw a histogram. How do you convert the character values into numerical values?

Comment: do you mean to say these x values are character representations of numbers? Like "65", and so on?

Comment: @buruzaemon: Yes

Answer (score 4):

You can use `as.numeric` to do this, as in

```
hist( as.numeric( c("0", "0", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4") ) )
```

Comment: How would you convert a year to a numeric value? For example, suppose you only have 2 years on the x-axis. The years are in the following form: 2004year.

Comment: @sasuser a<-"2004year"; as.numeric(substr(a,1,4))